# Преобразовать список координат точек в словарь в Python

Tags: python, list, dict

Есть список координат точек

```
[1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3]
```

Как из этого списка создать словарь вида

```
{"x1": 1, "y1": 1, "x2": 4, "y2": 1, ... }
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Однострочник для разминки

```
lst = [1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3]
{['x', 'y'][i%2]+str(i//2+1): v for i, v in enumerate(lst)}
#{'x1': 1, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 1, 'x3': 1, 'y3': 3, 'x4': 4, 'y4': 3}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как работает эта конструкция ['x', 'y'][i%2] ?

Comment: задаем список ['x', 'y'] берем элемент  с индексом i%2 - остаток от деления i на 2. По понятным причинам он будет чередоваться - 0 и 1...

Answer (score 1):

можно еще для разминки задействовать библиотеку itertools:

```
from itertools import cycle, count

c = cycle('xy')
n = count(1,0.5)

{k+str(int(i)):v for k,i,v in zip(c,n,lst)}
# {'x1': 1, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 4, 'y2': 1, 'x3': 1, 'y3': 3, 'x4': 4, 'y4': 3}
```